# Timed LOAD() in web2py not working

Tags: web2py

I haven't tried LOAD() before and I'm having trouble getting it to work. I'm currently using web2py2.8.2 and testing on localhost with the built-in server.

Here's my simplified example

---

### In default.py, I have

```
@auth.requires_login()
def monitor_manage():
    """ Controller for Monitor page """
    return dict()

@auth.requires_login()
def statehouse_poll():
    """ Controller for Monitor page """
    import time
    return dict(state=dict(timestamp=time.time()))
```

---

### default/monitor_manage.html

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

<h2>Monitor System Status</h2>
<p>Live monitoring of system state.

</p>
<div id="statehouse_component">
</div>
{{=LOAD(c='default', f='statehouse_poll.load', ajax=True,
         target="statehouse_component",
         user_signature=True,
         timeout=2000, times=100) }}
```

---

### default/statehouse_poll.load

```
{{=state}}
```

---

If I browse to default/statehouse_poll, I get the expected result, e.g.

```
 timestamp  : 1391807454.990959
```

but browsing to default/monitor_manage just shows

```
loading...
```

Inspecting the response html shows web2py is sending

```
<div data-w2p_remote="/arm_app/default/statehouse_poll.load?_signature=4addc7e2cd96daa1fbc88c233b163838d880c8c3" data-w2p_timeout="2000" data-w2p_times="100" id="statehouse_component">loading...</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT!: I found a message in the web2py group from Massimo that recommended copying the web2py.js file from the welcome app to fix a problem with LOAD().  Did that, but no effect in my case.

EDIT2: Per Anthony's suggestion I looked for errors with Chrome DevTools.  Found the following recurring error at 2 second intervals.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'parseHTML' web2py.js:382
$.web2py.web2py.updatePage web2py.js:382
$.ajax.complete web2py.js:311
n jquery.js:2
o.fireWith jquery.js:2
w jquery.js:4
d
```

Comment: Use the browser developer tools to check for JS errors in the console, and also see if the Ajax request actually goes out (and if so, what is returned).

Comment: @Anthony Thanks, see EDIT2 above. Does that suggest a fix?

Comment: Are you using a version of jQuery prior to 1.8?

Comment: @Anthony yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

-I'm able to solve the ajax problem by replacing the application's older jquery.js (1.7.1) with the newer version (1.10.2) that ships with web2py2.8.2. That provides the parseHTML() function needed by the newer web2py.js and the timed LOAD now runs as expected.

Doing this created a secondary problem with superfish.js because it tests for MSIE by checking browser.msie which was deprecated and removed from jQuery in version 1.9. Updating to the latest superfish fixed that.

I'm holding off for now on accepting my own answer in the hopes that someone from the web2py team can suggest a more automated migration strategy for bringing client-side dependencies up to date in older web2py apps.

Comment: web2py.js is considered part of the framework, so when you upgrade web2py, that should be the only app file that you *have* to upgrade as well (though occasionally you may also need to bump the jQuery version).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where using LOAD() I kept getting only “…loading” in the rendered page instead of the section that was supposed to load. In my case, the problem stemmed from not using layout.html, as I had built an alternative base.html in its place. My base.html did not include web2py’s 'web2py_ajax.html' -- which is found in layout.html’s head section as {{include 'web2py_ajax.html'}}. When I included that in my base.html, the problem resolved. I believe that web2py_ajax.html includes the javascript web2py relies on for LOAD().

I suspect this suggestion would not help the specific issue of this thread, but it could assist people troubleshooting similar issues.

Comment: Matt, your question is very hard to read and this directly proportional to understanding this question. Please use markdown formatting to make it easy for readers to understand.